# What is the difference between gtk_idle_add() and gtk_main_context_invoke() in gtk2?

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, glib, gtk2

I have an application that spawns a worker thread by calling g_thread_new(). The worker thread has to send progress information or probably occuring errors to the main thread that is updating the GUI based on received data.

Currently I'm using:

```
gtk_main_context_invoke(NULL, (GSourceFunc)update_gui, data);
```

with first parameter (of type GMainContext*) equal to NULL to run update_gui() in main loop context so that the worker can proceed doing the actual work.

When browsing the documentation I found a function:

```
guint g_idle_add (GSourceFunc function, gpointer data);
```

Would this function be more suitable for my application or should I use a completely different function for event transmission from worker to main thread?

Answer (score 3):

Those functions are equivalent. `g_main_context_invoke()` is a wrapper around `g_idle_add()` which avoids the need for message passing if called on a `GMainContext` which is owned by the current thread (which is not the case in your example, but is harmless).

Note that the function is `g_main_context_invoke()`, not `gtk_main_context_invoke()`. To the best of my knowledge, the latter does not exist. Similarly, it’s `g_idle_add()` not `gtk_idle_add()`.

Both `g_main_context_invoke()` and `g_idle_add()` are provided by GLib, not GTK. GTK uses GLib, but is not needed for this particular functionality.